# MySQL+Python Index Out of Range Error

Tags: python, mysql, cherrypy, jinja2

I am trying to get a country information after choosing a country name and pressing a button. I am using cherrypy, jinja, python and mysql. So I want the information to be shown on browser.

But when I press the submit button I get this error:

```
    countList=self.get_info(countryInfo)[0]    
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the main part of the code that is causing the problem.

```
@cherrypy.expose
    def get_Country_Info(self,countryInfo=None):
        self.get_Names()
        countList=self.get_info(countryInfo)[0]
        tmpl=env.get_template("submit_test.html")
        return tmpl.render(salutation="Welcome to", target="Country List", myList=self.country_list, country=countList )

def get_info(self,countryInfo):
        self.con.execute("SELECT Code, Name, Continent, Population, Capital FROM Country WHERE Name LIKE %s", (countryInfo,))
        self.countryDB=list(self.con.fetchall())
        return self.countryDB
```

Comment: is the resultset returned by `self.con.fetchall()` empty? if you cast an empty list to `list` it will beomce `[]` and indexing this will be out of range

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking [execute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) correctly.

Try: 
`self.con.execute("SELECT Code, Name, Continent, Population, Capital FROM Country WHERE Name LIKE ?", countryInfo)`